# Is there a way to store session information without using cookies?

Tags: http, cookies, server-side, session-state

I'd like to know if it's possible to somehow store session data that does not involve cookies. I tried to look it up but I could only find information involving cookies. I read about storing all data except the session id in the database, and then the id on a cookie, but it still involves cookies.

Is it possible or are cookies always required to some extent with sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Thing called "sessionId" in url -yes, in every request after session is created - is the alternative stuff.

In every request there is transferred stuff like
    `sessionId=456um2894myfy6273ynd2`

Then it is up to service side how to dig the session data based on this id.